# Narrow to Environment in AUCTeX

Tags: emacs, auctex, org-mode

I'd like to be able to use some `org-mode`-like features inside of AUCTeX.  In `org-mode`, you can narrow the buffer to a node or you can flatout send the node to a separate buffer for editing.

How can this be done in AUCTeX?  Specifically, I'd like to be able to perform a function that

- will determine the most specific environment it belongs in
- probably [utilize](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Narrowing.html) point and mark to capture the environment in its entirety
- do one of two things:

  - Narrow the buffer to this region (probably easiest)
  - Send this region to another buffer where relevant changes in either buffer are reflected in each, and saving the 'narrowed' buffer saves the original file.  (I'm not sure how this works internally in `org-mode`---see [`org-tree-to-indirect-buffer`](http://orgmode.org/worg/doc.html#org-tree-to-indirect-buffer) and [Indirect Buffers](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Indirect-Buffers.html) in the Emacs documentation.

The ideal option would be total emulation of `org-tree-to-indirect-buffer`, and would probably involve only a few steps

1. Making an indirect buffer from the current one
2. Rename that indirect buffer to something useful (maybe `buffername<envname>`?)
3. Narrowing the indirect buffer

Comment: `^C . ^X N N` will do this, i.e. mark environment followed by narrow to region.  You stay in the same buffer but only the environment is visible.

Comment: `LaTeX-mark-environment` may help (I'm working on this too)

Comment: @AndrewSwann Just saw your comment, and yeah - that works.  I'm still curious about the indirect buffer thing, but that sill probably turn out to be a simple application of the function I just mentioned.  It's always that last bit of research you do after you ask that holds the key...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Interactively you can do as you request by

```
C-x 4 c C-c . C-x n n
```

cloning the buffer, marking the enclosing environment and then narrow to that environment.  To build this as a single function, you need to pass appropriate arguments to the functions.

Firstly `clone-indirect-buffer` gets `nil` to use the default new name for the new buffer, and `t` to open it in a new window.

Marking is achieved by `LaTeX-mark-environment`, which needs no argument.

Finally, `narrow-to-region` requires the start and end of the region.  `LaTeX-mark-environment` has put `point` at the start and `mark` at the end.  The corresponding buffer positions are provided by the functions `(point)` and `(mark)`.

```lisp
(defun clone-focus-environment ()
  "Focus on the current environment.
   Clone the current buffer to an indirect buffer and narrow to the
   environment current the current point."
  (interactive "*")
  (clone-indirect-buffer nil t)
  (LaTeX-mark-environment)
  (narrow-to-region (point) (mark)))
```

Comment: This doesn't seem to work recursively; that is, if I have `\begin{a}\begin{b}\begin{c}...\end{c}\end{b}\end{a}` and narrow to `b`, I can't further narrow to `c` for some reason.

Comment: It works for me, even recursively, but you have to be positioned somewhere _after_ the starting backslash of `\begin`.  Also if the `\end`s are on the same line they will all be contained in the cloned buffer.  The behaviour comes from `LaTeX-mark-environment` which you can verify interactively using `C-c .`.

Comment: I suppose something may be wrong with my Emacs installation, then.  `LaTeX-mark-environment` works perfectly as expected, but further narrowing attempts fail.

Comment: For some reason, after cloning, point is being repositioned after the closing brace of the outermost environment.

Comment: If the marking is working as expected, it would surprise me if there something about the emacs installation.  I get the recursive effect by moving point forward into the inner environment in the cloned buffer before running the command again.  I am running aquamacs 2.4, based on gnu emacs 23.3.50.1.

Comment: I do the same... It *may* be because I'm using GNU Emacs 24(.3?) on OSX, not Aquamacs (but again, that would be *surprising*).  I think I have an effective idea for a fix; I'll edit that in what's I'm finished.  Thanks for your help!